# ios Message App extension insert sticker error code 6

Tags: ios, objective-c, message, ios-extensions

We developed a Message App extension written in obj-c. Right now we are having problems when inserting a GIF image using the method insertSticker.
The gif image is on a remote server and we first save it to local storage before inserting it to the active conversation.

We got this error description.
***Error Domain=com.apple.messages.stickers-error Code=6 "(null)"***

Comment: Did you resolve this error?

Comment: yes, same with what you found out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We got this error due to memory limit for GIF file. It is given in the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/messages) for `Messages` framework.

> 1. The image must be a PNG, APNG, GIF, or JPEG file.
> 2. The file must be less than 500 KB.
> 3. For the best results, the image should not be smaller than 100 x 100 points or larger than 206 x 206 points.

Comment: It saved my time. In my case my file size was larger than 500 KB.

Answer (score 0):

**Note: Sticker Sequence**

For image sequences, the maximum file size (all individual images together) is also 500 KB.